# How to disable yes command in linux

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any way to disable the command?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? If you don't want that your users can call that *yes* binary, just delete it? But of course, that would be pointless, because any user could create a similar tool easily. So, what are you actually asking?

Comment: Make your script expect something else (to confirm) other than `y` (or what `yes` outputs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your script expect something else (to confirm) other than `y` (or what `yes` outputs)

But again, the user can write a utility that outputs what your script expects.

Comment: Yes. I made changes in /etc/profile. Made an alias to do nothing when this command is entered. Thanks!